# How to know the situation when to use Mix Shader or Mix RGB?

Tags: shader-nodes

I try to simulate the fog in my setting, and here is the problem what I met. I don't know what the difference between the Mix shader and Mix RGB. I try to replace the Mix RGB shader to Mix shader in the shading, but it won't work. How does these two shaders work actually?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mix RGB is only for mixing between colours. Anything with a yellow dot on the node is outputting an RGBA value. Image Textures, Colour Ramp, Hue Saturation Value etc. If a colour node is plugged into a single value node (the grey dots), it takes the greyscale value of the colour.

The Mix Shader node can only be used to mix between Shaders and nothing else. Anything in the Shader submenu. They are the green dots on the nodes.

[image]

Comment: That was true until recently.  In recent versions of Blender you can plug other nodes into the mix shader and it treats them as if they were being passed through a diffuse (emission?) shader.

Comment: @Marty Fouts, yes but as you say it only works as if the color or image was plugged into an Emission, not a Diffuse. Also; maybe Benus should specify that MixRGB is also used to mix textures (which are colors of course)

Comment: You could go on for days with all the neat little tricks nodes have, like automatically converting RGB to XYZ and vice versa for example. I think I gave a clear explanation for beginners, which should suffice.

Comment: @moonboots  You can plug a color directly into a MixShader node now without plugging it into any shader at all.

Comment: @Benus any explanation that tells the beginner something that is not correct is not a clear explanation because when they encounter the variance later they'll be confused.  Give them incomplete information if you must but drop the "and nothing else" and you won't confuse them.

Comment: If you plugged Shader Nodes into only green nodes "and nothing else". I'd say you'd bump into less problems than if you didn't follow that rule. Even though I'd say my answer was "clear", I agree it isn't entirely true. So maybe calling it "the simple answer" is more fair. @MartyFouts

Comment: @ Marty Fouts yes but again it works as an Emission